# How to handle Typescript types in a model when there can be either of them?

Tags: angular, typescript, model, strong-typing

Depending on the business logic by model will have the expanded entity or just the ids in the model.Example,

```
class Order{
id:string;
product:Product
}
class Product{
id:string;
name:string;
price:number:
}
```

Now in the order response the product will be either expanded object or id if i havent requested the complete data. So how can i handle these in my ts model ? is using union on the order model good practice or should i have two different models ?

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear at the moment.

1. Regardless, if the features of class isn't required, I'd suggest using TS [`interface`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) instead. It supports type-checking without the "bloat" of class.
2. With that said, you could defined properties as [optional using `?:`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties). Then an object can be defined as that interface's type without the optional property.

```js
interface Order {
  id: string;
  product?: Product;   // <-- `product` is optional
}

interface Product {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  price: number;
}
```

Example

```js
const order: Order = { id: 'sample', product: {...} };  // <-- works
const order2: Order = { id: 'sample' };  // <-- works too
```

#### Update: `product` could be of type `Product` or `string`

You could use union types to define the type as either `Product` or `string`.

```js
interface Order {
  id?: string;
  product?: Product | string;
}
```

Comment: the product is not optional , suppose on some view i dont need the complete product details and only need the id at that instance my product is of type string , the response will be order = { product : '123uniqueid' } but on other views where i get the expanded data , same order will be order = { id : 'uniqueOrderId',product : {  id : '123uniqueid',name:'iphone',price:100000}

Comment: @NuraliKhoja: You could've posted this example in the question. I've updated the answer.

Comment: but when i have to do a property access when the type of data is product , the compiler shows the error that name does not exist on type string , in that case do i have to explicitly tell the compiler that it is of type product ? i am aware of the product = order.product as Product syntax ? is this the right way of doing it ?

Answer (score -1):

Then make the product like

product: string | Product;

Hope I understood your question!